# Javascript && operators not behaving in the preferred way?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm slowly learning JavaScript, and to this point I could figure everything out on my own. But I'm just spending waaay to much time at this problem.

Basically, I have two arrays, and if a number in the second array matches a number in the first array, it has to delete that number.

So the simplest solution I can think of is a for loop that loops through each property of the array, and if it doesn't match a number out of the second array, push it into a new array.

I have written this bit of code:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3], newArr = [2, 3, 3];
var finalArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) { 
 if (arr[i] != newArr[0] && arr[i] != newArr[1] && arr[i] != newArr[2]) 
     finalArr.push(arr[i]);
}

// ----> finalArr = [1]
```

The purpose is, it takes every value out of the array named "arr", compares it to a value of "newArr", and if the value doesn't match, push it into a new array.

Can anyone see the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't asked a good question or even said what the issue is. Please say what you expect it to do, and what's it's actually doing.

Comment: You are looping through `newArr`, not `arr`, is that the problem?

Comment: Which array should the number be deleted from, the first or second?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: The purpose is, it takes every value out of the array named "arr", compares it to a value of "newArr", and if the value doesn't match, push it into a new array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3], newArr = [2, 3, 3];
var finalArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    if (arr[i] != newArr[0] && arr[i] != newArr[1] && arr[i] != newArr[2]) 
        finalArr.push(arr[i]);
}

// result: [1,5,1]
```

This is your corrected code, just note that second array does not always need to contain three elements, you could loop through it as well with a for loop

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose is, it takes every value out of the array named "arr", compares it to a value of "newArr"...

You're not iterating over every value of `arr`, since you've `newArr.length` in your loop. You need to iterate till `arr.length` instead

> ...if the value doesn't match, push it into a new array.

Your code assumes `newArr` is always of length 3. Maybe it is. But, a more generic way is to use [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which *returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.*

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3],
  newArr = [2, 3, 3];
var finalArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (newArr.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) {
    finalArr.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(finalArr);
```